# Search Box implementation in React-leaflet v3.1.0 give an error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I used the kboul code to add a search box in React-leaflet v3.1.0, but I get this error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function", maybe beacause I already set an instance of map in my MapContainer option "whenCreated".
I can I use the same instance of the map that I defined in the MapContainer?

Here my code. Thanks for help!

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useMap } from "react";
    import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
    import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
    import "leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.css";
    import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from "leaflet-geosearch";
    
    import SearchForm from '../SearchForm'
    import "./map.css";
    import icon from "./constants";
    
    const zoom = 5;
    
    function Map({ regionCoord, regionName }) {
        const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
        const [position, setPosition] = useState()
        
        function FlyToButton() {
            const onClick = () => {
                map.locate().on("locationfound", function (e) {
                    setPosition(e.latlng);
                    map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom());
                });
            }
                // map.flyTo(regionCoord, zoom);
            return <button className="button" onClick={onClick}>Locate on click</button>;
        }
    
        function LeafletgeoSearch() {
            const map = useMap();
            useEffect(() => {
              const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
          
              const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
                provider,
                marker: {
                  icon
                }
              });
          
              map.addControl(searchControl);
          
              return () => map.removeControl(searchControl);
              // eslint-disable-next-line
            }, []);
          
            return null;
          }
        
        return (
            <>
            {/* create the button to geolocate */}
            <FlyToButton />
            {/* open the component SearchForm to create an input field to look for a city*/}
            <SearchForm />
            {/* create a map with coordinates from props */}
            {regionCoord && (
                <MapContainer
                    center={regionCoord}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    style={{ height: "90vh" }}
                    whenCreated={setMap}
                >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                  />
                  <Marker position={regionCoord} icon={icon}>
                    <Popup>{regionName}</Popup>
                  </Marker>
                {/* if position is located put a marker on new coordinates */}
                  {position && (
                    <Marker position={position} icon={icon}>
                        <Popup>Vous êtes ici</Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    )}
                     <LeafletgeoSearch />
                </MapContainer>
                )}
    
            </>
        );
    }
    
    export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and did not get the error you describe but several other errors:

The main problem is that you do not need to use useMap hook to get the map instance as you already have it from setMap. So delete this line

```
function LeafletgeoSearch() {
    const map = useMap(); // delete this line
    useEffect(() => {
      const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
...
}
```

Moreover dont  render  if the map instance is null

```
  {map && <LeafletgeoSearch />}
```

Here is a working[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-implementation-in-react-leaflet-v310-give-an-error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-fg92r?file=/src/Map.jsx) consisting all the parts of the app you have.

Comment: Thanks Kboul
You're very efficient, as usual!